# Error "Array ( [0] => HY000 [1] => 1 [2] => near "WHERE": syntax error" PHP + SQLite3

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm getting the above error when working in PHP/SQlite, never had this before, not sure why it's happening now... Here's a pastebin of the code http://pastebin.com/WBQphG8L and an imgur of the SQLite schema http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/543/schemaq.jpg/.

Any ideas what might be causing this and/or a possible fix?

Comment: Have you tried to isolate the problem?  Like by simplifying your code to the minimum possible that still causes the error?

Comment: try to print your query instead of execution. It is helpful

Comment: It seems it was some weird browser caching thing. All of a sudden it works, good tip with echoing the query though that reassured me that it was constructing right. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Adam: If you found your problem, post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Tomalak Apparently I'm too new to self-answer so soon, I'll set myself a reminder and close it when the timer expires.

Comment: @Adam: Look forward to reading your answer at that time.

Answer (score 1):

Your queries will fail to validate if `strtotime` fails in any way. It returns `false` in that case, and your query would look like

```
 UPDATE calendar SET compdate = WHERE ...
```

So check that you're not failing for that. Print out the query to debug.

Comment: $obeliskdate is result of strtotime so it's int and should not be quoted

Comment: You're right. Updated my answer with another possible candidate.

Comment: How is the code "very unsafe"? I don't see any injection vulnerabilities here.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that strtotime can't get result. Check your post data to be understanding by this function.